# Lightmap Pack: Vertices highlighted in bright red

Tags: uv

I'm attempting to use the Blender built-in Lightmap pack when unwrapping a mesh. In the UV window, some vertices are highlight in bright red. What does this indicate? I assume this must be indicating some type of error.

[image]

Comment: Those are pinned vertices, to unpin use Alt+P when the vertices selected in UV/Image Editor.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have pinned them by accident.